# how to convert byte[] in Modified-UTF8 to a String?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I'm learning about class file format.

And I encountered with a Modified-UTF8 encoded byte[].

Is there any handy way to convert that byte[] into a String without DataInput#readUTF?

I couldn't find any charset name for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try decoding with the regular `UTF-8` charset name. The only difference in Modified UTF-8 is a non-canonical encoding of the zero codepoint and since in all probability your string doesn't contain zero characters, it will get decoded properly.

Comment: And what about 4-byte UTF-8 characters??

Comment: Modified UTF-8 encoder never emits 4-byte UTF-8 characters, that is clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: This answer says `you should try` and `there is a good chance`, or in other words you do not know for sure, it is just guess that maybe the UTF-8 charset decoder does the right thing but you don't know yourself. So I am asking: Did you try? Do you know that it actually does work? Or does it maybe not work at all because after all it is just a guess that is presented here.

Comment: @scravy In my answer I clearly documented when it will and when it won't work. There is no guessing. It is up to you to know what your particular input is. Have you tried it already, or are you only interested in a general discussion on this topic?